# SciPy Spatial equivalent for JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, scipy

I'm attempting to use an equivalent function for [scipy.spatial.HalfspaceIntersection](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.HalfspaceIntersection.html) in a TS project, i.e. something like:

```
const halfspaces: number[][] = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], ...];
const feasiblePoint: number[] = [0,0,0];
const halfspaceIntersections = sciPyHalfSpaceIntersection(halfspaces, feasiblePoint, true);
```

In python I would normally do something like:

```py
halfspaces = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]])
feasible_point = np.array([0., 0., 0.])
hs = HalfspaceIntersection(halfspaces, feasible_point, incremental=True)
```

Is there a JS/TS equivalent to do so?

Comment: Find a library to do it or write your own code to compute it.